# Get Date Range in UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc, dst

I have the following range that needs to be calculated:

```
const range = (new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate))
```

Where startDate and endDate are: `"2020-11-03 17:34:24"`,  `"2021-05-06 18:34:1"`

How can I convert this to using UTC so that the seconds will remain the same for all browsers?

I was thinking of converting them using `Date(startDate).toISOString()` then feeding that in the newDate object would that make sense?

Comment: You can use Date.UTC() as described at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: The answer will very much depend on what exactly you are passing for `startDate` and `endDate`, which you haven't shown here.  Please edit your question to provide sample values.  (In particular, are they strings, numbers, objects, etc?)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint updated

Comment: Is your intention that those strings represent UTC time, or the user's local time?  (also, is that a typo in the seconds of the endDate?)

Comment: @MattJonson-Pint UTC. It can't be user's time because I have a calculation that needs to be consistent in all areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that it is in the [ECMAScript Date Time String Format](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) (similar to ISO 8601).  That means the date and time portions should be separated by a `T`, and for UTC values it should end with a `Z`.

In your case, since your input values are like `"2020-11-03 17:34:24"` and are in terms of UTC, you can do some string manipulation before parsing.

```
const start = new Date(startDate.replace(' ', 'T').concat('Z'));
const end = new Date(endDate.replace(' ', 'T').concat('Z'));
const seconds = (end - start) / 1000;
```

Comment: thanks i'm going to test this now. Out of curiosity, is there a way to add timezone to a date object to do the following? Eg. calculate total sum of seconds from objects from different timezones (some that have daylight savings and some that don't)

Comment: No.  The `Date` object only has one internal value - a Unix Timestamp in terms of milliseconds (UTC-based).  It does not store any time zone information.  You might consider [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead.